# how to extract subarrays from an array using perl

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose that I have this array. (Perl)

```
@arr= ((a,b,c),(a,2,3,4,5,j),(l),(t,x,51));
```

**How do I extract the subarrays? Also, how do I determine the index of each subarray?**
Thanks in advance!

Comment: the array you wrote is the same as (a,b,c,a,2,3,4,5,j,l,t,x,51). This is not how you build multidimensional arrays, you have to use references instead

Comment: Also, your piece of code throws an error, so I guess you are not using `strict` nor `warnings`  you should always use them

Comment: I would like to thank you people for helping me out by taking of your time                    my @arr= (['a','b','c'],['a',2,3,4,5,'j'],['l'],['t','x',51]);

#prints all elements
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i= $i+1) {
    foreach my $arrRef(@arr[$i]) {      // gives me access to each of my subarray 
        foreach my $element(@$arrRef) { // gives me access to each of my element in a subarray
            print "$element\n";
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses just affect precedence. Perl will flatten what you think is array of arrays into a single array. In order to simulate an array or arrays, you would need to actually create an array of array references ([],[],[]) as shown below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @arr= (['a','b','c'],['a',2,3,4,5,'j'],['l'],['t','x',51]);

print $arr[0]->[1]; #prints b
print $arr[1]->[2]; #prints 3

#prints all elements
foreach my $arrRef(@arr) {
    foreach my $element(@$arrRef) {
        print "$element\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me by taking you time i got what i exactly want and i shall post the solution

Answer (score 1):

First of all, like [Flying_whale said in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52427005/how-to-extract-subarrays-from-an-array-using-perl#comment91797256_52427005), in Perl  lists are always flattened. Multi-dimensional lists do not exist. That means

```
( 1, 2, 3, (4, 5) )
```

is the same as

```
( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
```

or

```
( 1, (2, (3, (4, (5, () ) ) ) ) )
```

They all get flattened.

> How do I extract the subarrays **using their size** or determine index of end of each element?

You say you know the size of each element. In that case, you have several options.

```
# index               0 1 2      3 4 5 6 7 8      9      10 11 12
my @long_array = ( qw(a b c), qw(a 2 3 4 5 j), qw(l), qw(t  x  51));

my @abc    = @long_array[0 .. 2];
my @a2345j = @long_array[3 .. 8];
my $l      = $long_array[9];
my @tx51   = @long_array[10, 11, 12];
```

This is mostly using *array slices*, which is why the *sigil* of `@long_array[0 .. 2]` is an `@`, and not a `$`, because the expression returns a *list* and not a *scalar*.

An alternative is to use [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html), but that would alter your initial array.

In either case you **have to know the start and length** of each individual sub list. Since there are no sub lists, this is the only way to get each piece of data. If you don't know both start index and length, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

some ways..

```
@var_ref_array = (
            [ "a", "b",    "c" ],
            [ "d", "e",    "f" ],
            [ "g"] );

for my $i ( 0 .. $#{var_ref_array})
{
    for my $j ( 0 .. $#{var_ref_array->[$i]})
    {
        print "$var_ref_array[$i][$j]";
    }    
}

printf "\n";

for(my $i=0; $i<$#{var_ref_array}+1; $i++){ 
    for(my $j=0; $j<$#{var_ref_array->[$i]}+1; $j++){
        print "$var_ref_array[$i][$j]";
    }
}

printf "\n";

for(my $i=0; $i<scalar @var_ref_array; $i++){ 
    for(my $j=0; $j<scalar @{$var_ref_array[$i]}; $j++){
        print "$var_ref_array[$i][$j]";
    }
}

printf "\n";

for(my $i=0; $i<scalar @var_ref_array; $i++){ 
    for(my $j=0; $j<scalar @{var_ref_array->[$i]}; $j++){
        print "$var_ref_array[$i][$j]";
    }
}

printf "\n";

for my $i ( 0 .. @var_ref_array)
{
    for my $j ( 0 .. @{$var_ref_array[$i]})
    {
        print "$var_ref_array[$i][$j]";
    }    
}

printf "\n";

for my $i ( 0 .. @var_ref_array)
{
    for my $j ( 0 .. @{var_ref_array->[$i]})
    {
        print "$var_ref_array[$i][$j]";
    }    
}

printf "\n";

foreach my $array_(@var_ref_array){
    foreach my $element(@$array_){
        print "$element";
    }
}
```